# Trouble getting jQuery to work in Kube for interactive elements

Tags: jquery, frameworks, frontend

I recently came across this framework Kube and it seems very appealing and fun to work with, but there's not a lot of material online when it comes to trouble-shooting. I will admit, I'm not INCREDIBLY proficient with jQuery and interactive web development, but I have successfully used jQuery with other frameworks including Bootstrap and Materialize.

I'm specifically having trouble trying to get modals and collapses to work in Kube, and I'm not sure where to place the jQuery and how to format it, and what I'm doing wrong. I took the code from the "Quick Start" page (https://imperavi.com/kube/docs/quick-start/) and built a template using that, and then took the code from the API section in the Collapse page (https://imperavi.com/kube/docs/collapse/) and tried plugging that in, with the jQuery from below, but I can't get the boxes to open and close. I had a similar problem with the modals in this framework.

Here is my code. Any help is much appreciated:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Basic Template</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Kube CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kube/6.5.2/css/kube.css">


</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div id="my-collapse" data-component="collapse">

       <button onclick="$('#my-collapse-api').collapse('open', '#box-2');">Open</button>
        <button onclick="$('#my-collapse-api').collapse('close', '#box-2');">Close</button>
        <button onclick="$('#my-collapse-api').collapse('openAll');">Open All</button>
        <button onclick="$('#my-collapse-api').collapse('closeAll');">Close All</button>

        <div id="my-collapse-api" data-component="collapse">

            <h4><a href="#box-1" class="collapse-toggle">Box 1</a></h4>
            <div class="collapse-box hide" id="box-1"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ut sapien malesuada, elementum ligula a, vestibulum odio. Quisque sed dapibus lacus. Etiam mollis congue vestibulum. Sed maximus dolor id ligula finibus rutrum.</p>L</div>

            <h4><a href="#box-2" class="collapse-toggle">Box 2</a></h4>
            <div class="collapse-box hide" id="box-2"><p>Nam fringilla velit quis lacus sollicitudin, et molestie orci ultricies. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam nec dolor mattis nulla tincidunt posuere id ut elit. Sed eu augue at odio vestibulum convallis. Proin sollicitudin accumsan elit non mattis.</p></div>

            <h4><a href="#box-3" class="collapse-toggle">Box 3</a></h4>
            <div class="collapse-box hide" id="box-3"><p>Maecenas a auctor tellus. Mauris condimentum rutrum pellentesque. Maecenas volutpat id eros at gravida. Sed accumsan magna at congue ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras efficitur erat sit amet risus iaculis dignissim. Sed et rutrum ante. Praesent maximus erat eu magna tincidunt, elementum molestie nisi lobortis.</p></div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Kube JS + jQuery are used for some functionality, but are not required for the basic setup -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/kube.js"></script>

    <script>

      $('#my-collapse').collapse('open');

      $('#my-collapse').collapse('close');

      $('#my-collapse').collapse('openAll');

      $('#my-collapse').collapse('closeAll');

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery as part of inline bindings, >_<

Comment: not sure.. as you can probably tell i'm not super experienced on this front. what would be the alternative?